# How to dispose controller on demand?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Edit-: A relevant question also would be How to dispose multiple controllers dynamically?

I have a custom painter in which each object needs to be animated individually. And after certain time data gets added to the list and I paint it and animate it.

Here what it looks like,

The is the model class for animation

```
class Wave {
  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation<double> animation;
  bool isDisposed;

  Wave({
    required this.animationController,
    required this.animation,
    this.isDisposed = false,
  });
}
```

```
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
for (var i = 0; i < waveData.length; i++) {
    addAnimatedWaves(i); // <------- a callback to add animation model to list
    animatedWaves[i].animationController.forward();
    canvas.drawLine(...);

   if (animatedWaves[i].animationController.status ==
            AnimationStatus.dismissed &&
    !animatedWaves[i].isDisposed) { //<------ trying to dispose but it won't get executed
      animatedWaves[i].animationController.dispose();
      animatedWaves[i].animation.removeListener(() {});
      animatedWaves[i].isDisposed = true;
    }
 }
}
```

This is the above mentioned call back,

```
 void addAnimatedWaves(int i) {
    if (_waves.isEmpty) {
      var controller = AnimationController(
          vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
      _waves.add(Wave(
        animationController: controller,
        animation: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeIn),
        ),
      ));
    } else {
      if (_waves.length > i) {
        var controller = AnimationController(
            vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
        _waves.add(Wave(
          animationController: controller,
          animation: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(parent: controller, curve: Curves.easeIn),
          ),
        ));
      }
      _waves[i].animation.addListener(() {
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
      });
    }
  }
```

disposing

```
@override
  void dispose() {
   for (var wave in _waves) { // it always calls every dispose method because every 
                                // controller is active
      if (!wave.isDisposed) {
        wave.animationController.dispose();
        wave.animation.removeListener(() {});
      }
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```

what I want is to immediately dispose a controller when the animation is completed. And
optimise the for loop at the end so that it doesn't have length of whole list.

So can anyone suggest what should do or Is there any better method to animate list of objects which needs to individually animated?

Comment: I don't have any experience with custom painters, but what I notice from your code is that all waves are sharing the same controller, meaning there's no point to `dispose` the controller separately for each wave because it's the same object, so a single dispose should be sufficient. Secondly, I notice you do `removeListener` with parameter a new empty listener. This won't do anything because you need to provide a reference to the actual listener

Comment: @IvoBeckers each time `addAnimatedWaves()` gets called wouldn't it create new controller because I'm defining it locally and for remove listener how do suggest to do it, like this `for(var i=0;i<_waves.length;i++){_waves[i].animation.removeListener((){})}` ?

Comment: ok so for remove listener par I have to use mentioned method in comment

Comment: oh yeah, you're right, I misread the addAnimatedWaves function. Somehow I thought you were making multiple waves there with the same controller, but now I see that isn't the case

Comment: `paint()` should only paint the stuff on the canvas, it should not forward the controller, nor dispose it

Comment: @pskink do you suggest to dispose all at once with for loop in dispose method and I can forward that controller inside the `addAnimatedWaves` method

Comment: i dont really know what you are trying to achieve but adding `AnimationController` inside each frame of `CustomPainter` animation ends up with dozens / hundreds  of controllers, cannot you just use one controller and couple of `Interval`s?

Comment: @pskink actually every 100ms I get audio data which draws a wave. Now what I want is a wave at index `i` should continue it's animation when a wave at index `i+1` gets added. So for this scenario I don't know how can I add `interval` and yes for like 2-3 seconds it adds 1000+ controllers that's why I'm trying to optimise it

Comment: so you just need only one animation at a time? (animating index `i` until `i + 1` is added after 100ms)?

Comment: @pskink no if I set animation duration to 500ms then it will require maybe 5 different controllers because first waves' animation is not completed yet and it adds second wave

Comment: so why dont you use a fixed array of 5 controllers then?

Comment: @pskink thank you for your suggestions I have resolved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have found this solution if anyone have better solution then I'm happy to change the accepted answer.

First, @pskink suggested that we should not use controllers inside paints so removed them and added inside `addAnimatedWave()`

```
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
   if (animatedWaves.isEmpty) {
        addAnimatedWaves(i);//---->for first time
      } else {
       if (animatedWaves.isNotEmpty && i >= animatedWaves.length - 1) {
         addAnimatedWaves(i);
        }
      }
    canvas.drawLine(...);
}
```

the above condition checks whether the index contains any value or not.
So if it contains then it is not required and it skips it.

```
 void _addAnimatedWave(int i) {
    if (_waves.isEmpty) {
      _addWave(); // <--- it just creates new controller and adds to _waves
                  //you can refer it from question.
    } else {
      if (_waves.length > i) {
        _addWave();
      }
      _waves[i].animationController.forward();
      _waves[i].animation.addListener(() {
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
      });
      _waves[i].animationController.addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          _waves[i].animationController.dispose();
          _waves[i].animation.removeListener(() {});
          _waves[i].isDisposed = true;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Here we are adding a listener to every `AnimationController` but it will active till an animation completes for the controller and we are immediately disposing it.

so for my case a single controller will be `active` for `300ms`.

Before it was adding `1000+` controller every `2-3 seconds` now it only adds a controller for every wave bar.

Now for the remaining controller which are still active, while widget is removed from widget tree.

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    for (var i = _waves.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (_waves[i].isDisposed) {
        break;
      }
      _waves[i].animationController.dispose();
      _waves[i].animation.removeListener(() {});
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```

For my case disposing a controller was `linear` so if we `reverse` the list and reach to the `first` controller which was disposed, after that every controller would be disposed so we don't require to go through whole list so we can just `break` that loop.

And with this optimisation, I notice only `max 3` controllers were required to be disposed with for-loop.